# Importing bootstrap 4 to Angular CLI app

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap 4 `collapse` method from inside the navbar component in my Angular 4 App created using Angular CLI.

The issue is as follows. I import jquery and bootstrap using this code:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
```

And then have this event handler to collapse the navbar when link in it is clicked:

```
$('#navbarToggleArea .nav-link').on('click', function () {
  $('#navbarToggleArea').collapse('hide');
});
```

Code is compiled successfully using `ng serve` or `ng build` commands, but fails at runtime, as if the bootstrap plugin was not added to jQuery. When `collapse` function is being called the error is thrown:

> vendor.bundle.js:60854 ERROR TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery**(...).collapse is not a function

My question is: what and how should I configure to eliminate this error?

Code is [here](https://github.com/kosmakoff/lil-blogger-a4-app/tree/typed-jquery-extension), and the component under question is [here](https://github.com/kosmakoff/lil-blogger-a4-app/blob/typed-jquery-extension/src/app/nav/nav.component.ts).

Comment: i agree with the answer you should use angular way to do such things but there are some cases in which you may need to import third party JS .[check this link for info ](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq)

Comment: No, third party component with typings doesn't work in my case. It works without typing though, but I'd prefer to use typed version if possible.

Comment: You will get typings for bootstrap as it is a popular lib. Or you need to create it on your own. Which is a bit cumbersome

Comment: I have also answered an Angular way to make it work please check

Answer (score 0):

To achieve collapsing, use angular:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" [class.in]='collapsed'>
```

on the 'humburger'

```
<span [class.open]="collapsed" id="humburger" (click)="collapsed=!collapsed">
```

in the class:

`collapse:boolean`;

Comment: Or use a dedicated library that provides Bootstrap 4 + Angular integration: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: Unfortunately, ng-bootstrap can't animate collapsible div.

Answer (score 0):

Angular way to achieve this used in my page [myPage](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq)

**Bootstrap Navbar**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded  navbar-fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="isActive = !isActive">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown" [ngClass] = "{show : isActive}"> // ngClass used here
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown [routerLinkActive]="['active']" appDropdown"> // directive used here
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**appDropdown Directive**

```
import {Directive, HostListener, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
    selector: '[appDropdown]'
  })
  export class DropdownDirective {

    private isOpen:boolean = false;

    @HostBinding('class.open') get opened(){
      return this.isOpen;
    }
    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('click')open(){
      this.isOpen = true;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave')close(){
      this.isOpen = false;
    }
  }
```